# Partially syncing client state using ngrx

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, server, ngrx

I would like to synchronize the state of an Angular application across clients. I have written a simple node server that relays the messages sent to it via a websocket to all other clients (code below). I would like to keep the server simple.

```
const server = new WebSocket.Server({port: this.port});
server.on("connection", ws => {
  ws.on("message", data => {
    server.clients.forEach((client: WebSocket) => {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(data);
      } }); }); });
```

On the client/Angular side, I use ngrx to store/update the state. Currently, I subscribe to any changes in the state, and whenever it happens, I sent the whole state object via the websocket. When I receive the message I load the state, making sure to not send the message this time:

```
this.store.pipe(select("test")).subscribe(state => {
  if (!state.forcefullyChanged) this.ws.sendState(state);
});

this.ws.messages$.subscribe(state => {
  this._loadState(state);
  this.store.dispatch(forceChangeState(state));
});
```

The problem with that is that the state consists of a multiple (long) arrays:

```
export interface State {
  a: Array<SomeOtherObject>;
  b: Array<SomeObject[]>;
}
```

most of the time, the change will correspond to changing just one element of `SomeObject`: I would like to allow different clients to change these independently without overwriting each other changes.

I know about the more sophisticated solutions to these, like using Meteor or setting up a proper database. I could set up an observer for every element of the array, but that may be tiresome, as I often add/remove elements from the middle of those. Ideally, I would get the ngrx selector to return which cell of the array changed and I would send just the new cell and its index to the server. Is that possible? Is there a more canonical way to get partial updates of the state (on the level of array elements, and not fields)?

Comment: what about to just share the action+payload with other clients instead the whole state?

Comment: that would be more risky than the selector-based solution in case there are two concurrent actions that lead to different states when executed in different order (whereas when I'm sending (partial) updates, I'll get consistency).
But overall, that would make sense. Do I guess correctly that I'd need to override .dispatch if I don't want to pollute my code with messages whenever I need to send the action over? How would I do this?

Comment: dont monkey-patch `dispatch`. I would try to use `actions$` without the `ofType()` operator, so you take every action. Then simply popuplate every action to your websocket-connection. Note that you need this "sending"-effect set to "dispatch:false" or you will end up in a endless loop

Comment: another thought: If you always want to share the exactly same state to every client, the master-state should live on the server-side and synchronize with the client states - but this for sure would lead to a more heavy server codebase